# how to upload a base64_decode($data) using ftp?

Tags: php, ftp, type-conversion

Im trying to upload a mp3 file to my ftp server:

```
$data = substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ",") + 1);
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
$filename = urldecode($_POST['fname']);

$cid = ftp_connect("foo.com");
$result = ftp_login($cid, "rodrigo@foo.com","password");

if ((!$cid) || (!$result)) {
    echo "connection failed"; die;
} else {
    echo "connected";
}

ftp_pasv ($cid, true);
ftp_chdir($cid, "my_folder");

if (ftp_put($cid, $filename, $decodedData, FTP_BINARY)) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

I have this warning:

```
Warning:  ftp_put(���) [function.ftp-put]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in...
```

I cant find out how to send a valid argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a file that you can pass, the below example writes the file to memory instead of a file on your disk ... but you may want to write it to disk depending on the size.

```
$tmp = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fputs($tmp, $decodedData);
rewind($tmp);

if (ftp_fput($cid, $filename, $tmp, FTP_BINARY)) {

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but now I have this warning:
        `Warning:  ftp_put() expects parameter 3 to be string, resource given in...`

Comment: I have updated my answer to use the correct function `ftp_fput`